# object type value get ignored on newtonsoft serialization

Tags: c#, json.net

Want to get serialized output with ignored default value. In my case, i have defined default value as null for object property. Facing issue with ignoring type based default value for object data. find the below tried codes.

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
            myClass.item1 = false;
            myClass.item2 = 0;
            myClass.item3 = "test";
            myClass.item4 = new { item1Val = false, item2Val = 0, item3Val = "test" };


            var output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myClass, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings
                {
                    DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore,
                    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
                });

//...

public class MyClass
    {
        [DefaultValue(true)]
        public bool item1 { get; set; }

        [DefaultValue(10)]
        public int item2 { get; set; }

        [DefaultValue("")]
        public string item3 { get; set; }

        [DefaultValue(null)]
        public object item4 { get; set; }
    }
```

Actual output:

```
{
  "item1": false,
  "item2": 0,
  "item3": "test",
  "item4": {
    "item3Val": "test"
  }
}
```

Expected output:

```
{
  "item1": false,
  "item2": 0,
  "item3": "test",
  "item4": {
    "item1Val": false,
    "item2Val": 0,
    "item3Val": "test"
  }
}
```

Note:
I need this global setting DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore,
& NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore.

Anyone provide suggestion on this.

Comment: You need DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Include to get the expected output. Otherwise you need to specify a proper type with defined DefaultValues instead of "object".

Comment: Any possible ways to ignore this only for object type? I'm confused in this case, is any type based default value predefined internally (i.e bool (false), integer (0),) since i didn't defined these default value anywhere. I guessed the DefaultValueHandling is depends with [DefaultValue] attribute only.

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51691331/json-net-get-default-values-from-auto-property-initializer